# Minimum Depth of Binary Tree: recursive program always returns 0

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree, depth-first-search

I am trying to do the LeetCode problem [111. Minimum Depth of Binary Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-depth-of-binary-tree/):

> Given a binary tree, find its minimum depth.
>
> The minimum depth is the number of nodes along the shortest path from the root node down to the nearest leaf node.
>
> **Note:** A leaf is a node with no children.

My code runs, but doesn't change the minimum depth value at all. I've asked my classmates and a teacher, but they don't know why it won't work either. I've spent a lot of time trying to figure it out.

This is my code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int minHeight = 0, currHeight = 0;

    int minDepth(TreeNode* root) {
        searchTree(root);
        return minHeight;
    }

    void searchTree(TreeNode* p) {
        currHieght++;
        if (p->right == nullptr && p->left == nullptr) 
        {
            if (currHeight < minHeight) minHeight = currHeight--;
            return;
        }
        else if (p->right == nullptr)
            searchTree(p->left);
        else if (p->left == nullptr)
            searchTree(p->right);
        else
        {
            searchTree(p->left);
            searchTree(p->right);
            currHeight--;
        }

    }
};
```

Whatever the input, my code always returns 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `if (currHeight < minHeight) minHeight = currHeight;` So `minHeight` always stuck at 0.

Comment: Set `minHeight` to something big like `1000000000` at the beginning. As a general rule if you want minimum set its default value unrealistically big, so all numbers (heights) will be smaller, If you want maximum set the default to unrealistically small.

Comment: *I've asked my classmates and a teacher but they don't know why it wont work either* -- And within a half-hour, StackOverflow provides the information that your "teacher" should have provided.  Next time, don't rely on classmates or even your "teacher" -- instead, [debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) your code.

Comment: Also, **do not post pictures of the code**.  Copy the code as text and paste it in the edit window.

Answer (score 1):

There are the following issues in your code:

- `minHeight` is initialised as 0, so it could never get a greater value. This means whatever input your code gets, it will **always** return 0. `minHeight` should be set to an extremely great value, like `INT_MAX`, so that *any* leaf will have a lesser depth than that initial value.
- The code has undefined behaviour when an *empty* tree is given as input. That boundary case should be checked.
- `currHeight` is not always decreased when it should. Whatever the case in that `if ...else if ... else if ...` structure -- `currHeight` should be decreased. This is not done for the two middle cases. It will be better to perform this `currHeight--` at a common place, at the end of the function body.

Here is your code with those corrections:

```
    int minHeight = INT_MAX, // Set at an extreme high value
        currHeight = 0;

    int minDepth(TreeNode* root) {
        if (root != nullptr) return 0; // boundary case: empty tree
        searchTree(root);
        return minHeight;
    }

    void searchTree(TreeNode* p) {
        currHeight++;
        if (p->right == nullptr && p->left == nullptr) 
        {
            // Don't increase currHeight here, but at a common spot in the code
            if (currHeight < minHeight) minHeight = currHeight;
        }
        else if (p->right == nullptr)
            searchTree(p->left);
        else if (p->left == nullptr)
            searchTree(p->right);
        else
        {
            searchTree(p->left);
            searchTree(p->right);
        }
        currHeight--; // Always do this

    }
```

Note that this is not the most efficient way to tackle the problem. This algorithm will visit *all* nodes, while a breadth-first traversal could stop as soon as a leaf is found.

Here is a spoiler solution using breadth-first traversal:

> `int minDepth(TreeNode* root) {
>         if (root == nullptr) return 0;
>         vector<TreeNode*> level, nextLevel;
>         level.push_back(root);
>         for (int depth = 1; true; depth++) {
>             nextLevel.clear();
>             for (auto node : level) {
>                 if (node->left == nullptr && node->right == nullptr)
>                     return depth; // found the first leaf: solved!
>                 if (node->left != nullptr)
>                     nextLevel.push_back(node->left);
>                 if (node->right != nullptr)
>                     nextLevel.push_back(node->right);
>             }
>             level = nextLevel; // copy
>         }
>     }`